# CMake: How can I make add_custom_command output up-to-date by default?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, cmake

I have a software environment based on CMake 3.11.4 and Python 3.7.

My libraries/programs have a `config.txt` file describing their dependencies in a format I specified. Then, I have a Python script (`scripts/configure.py`) that generates `CMakeLists.txt` on the fly and later calls CMake to generate a solution that can be built by Visual Studio 2015.

I want Python to be run again automatically when `config.txt` is edited by the user.

So I made my Python script add a custom command statement in the generated `CMakeLists.txt`. Here is how it looks like for a project named "myproject" including two libraries "lib1" and "lib2".

`${SDE_ROOT_DIR}/build/myproject/CMakeLists.txt` contains:

```
# Automatically re-run configure project when an input file changes:
set( PROJECT_DEPENDENCIES )
list( APPEND PROJECT_DEPENDENCIES "${SDE_ROOT_DIR}/lib/lib1/config.txt" )
list( APPEND PROJECT_DEPENDENCIES "${SDE_ROOT_DIR}/lib/lib2/config.txt" )
ADD_CUSTOM_COMMAND( OUTPUT ${SDE_ROOT_DIR}/build/myproject/CMakeLists.txt COMMAND tools/python/Python370/python.exe scripts/configure.py myproject WORKING_DIRECTORY ${SDE_ROOT_DIR} DEPENDS ${PROJECT_DEPENDENCIES} )
```

Here is what I do:

- I run my script (`scripts/configure.py myproject`) to have the `CMakeLists.txt` and the Visual Studio solution generated.
- Then I open the solution
- The first time I build, it reports `Generating CMakeLists.txt` and I see that my script `scripts/configure.py` is invoked. **This is not expected!**
- The second time I build, nothing happens. This is OK.
- If I edit `config.txt`, the next time I build I see `Generating CMakeLists.txt` and I see that my script `scripts/configure.py` is invoked. That's good.

It's almost what I expected except the fact that my script is run the first time I compile the project. As `CMakeLists.txt` was just generated and is definitely newer than `config.txt`, I don't understand why it needs to generate `CMakeLists.txt` again.

Any idea what I could be doing wrong? Is there any additional command I should add to the `CMakeLists.txt` to make this custom command's output be "up to date" by default?

---

Here is a MCVE (`config.txt` is replaced by `prgname.txt`):

`prg/main.cpp`:

```
#include <iostream>

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    std::cout << "Hello World!" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

`prg/prgname.txt`:

```
myprogram
```

`scripts/configure.py`:

```
import sys
import subprocess
import argparse
import os
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def pushd(newDir):
    previousDir = os.getcwd()
    os.chdir(newDir)
    yield
    os.chdir(previousDir)

def configure_project():

    # check configuration args
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="CMakeLists generator.")
    parser.add_argument('project',  metavar='project', type=str, help='project name')
    args = parser.parse_args()

    working_directory = os.getcwd()

    project = args.project

    buildfolder = os.path.normpath(os.path.join( os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), os.pardir, "build", project ))

    if not os.path.isdir(buildfolder):
        os.makedirs(buildfolder)

    prgsourcefolder = os.path.normpath(os.path.join( os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), os.pardir, "prg" ))
    prgbuildfolder = os.path.join( buildfolder, "prg" )
    if not os.path.isdir(prgbuildfolder):
        os.makedirs(prgbuildfolder)

    prgnamepath = os.path.join( prgsourcefolder, "prgname.txt" )
    with open( prgnamepath, "r" ) as prgnamefile:
        prgname = prgnamefile.read()

    with open( os.path.join( prgbuildfolder, "CMakeLists.txt" ), "w" ) as cmakelists:
        cmakelists.write( "add_executable(" + prgname + " " + os.path.join(prgsourcefolder,"main.cpp").replace("\\","/") + ")\n" )

    cmakelistspath = os.path.join( buildfolder, "CMakeLists.txt" )
    with open( cmakelistspath, "w" ) as maincmakelists:
        maincmakelists.write( "cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.11)\n" )
        maincmakelists.write( "project(" + project + ")\n" )
        maincmakelists.write( "add_subdirectory(prg)\n" )

        maincmakelists.write( "add_custom_command( OUTPUT " + cmakelistspath.replace("\\","/") + " COMMAND python " + " ".join( [ x.replace("\\","/") for x in sys.argv] ) + " WORKING_DIRECTORY " + working_directory.replace("\\","/") + " DEPENDS " + prgnamepath.replace("\\","/") + ")\n" )

    # Run CMake:
    with pushd( buildfolder ):
        cmd = ['cmake.exe', '-G', 'Visual Studio 14 2015 Win64', buildfolder]
        proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
        while True:
            out = proc.stdout.read(1)
            if proc.poll() != None:
                break   
            sys.stdout.write(out.decode())
            sys.stdout.flush()
        proc.wait()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    sys.exit( configure_project() )
```

- Add CMake and Python to your `PATH`
- From the scripts folder run `python configure.py myproject`
- Open `build/myproject/myproject.sln`
- Hit "compile all" and you'll see the unexpected message `Generating CMakeLists.txt` in the log

Comment: You are not specifying which version of CMake you are using. I've seen in a comment of yours you expect it to run in VS2015, so these are some important details you are missing from your representative working example.

Comment: @JorgeBellon: True, just added this in my post.

Answer (score 0):

`add_custom_command` creates a command that no target depends on. Because of that, it won't be executed. I have no idea why Visual Studio runs it anyway the first time, but on Linux the Python script never runs.

For it to work properly, you also need a target. In this case, you can use [`add_custom_target`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_custom_target.html#command:add_custom_target) with the `ALL` option and specify the output of the custom command as its dependency. This way, the custom target will run the command if needed.

Just add a line like

```
        maincmakelists.write( "add_custom_target( Configure ALL DEPENDS " + cmakelistspath.replace("\\","/") + " )\n" )
```

after the one where you write `add_custom_command` and it should work. It did for me.

Note that the custom target will always run, but the custom command will only run when the *prgname.txt* file is modified.

Comment: Hi. Thank you for having a look at my problem. Unfortunately, this does not fix it. Having this custom target only makes the "Configure" project appear in VS (then I can manually run it on demand). But, it does not prevent VS from running it first time I compile which is what I want to avoid.

Comment: @jpo38 Judging by the fact that Visual Studio runs the command even without a target attached might indicate that won't be possible to avoid. Afterwards, does it only rerun the Python script when you modify prgname.txt?

Comment: Yes, it runs it first time I compile and then it won't run it untill I modify prgname.txt. So it is apparently able to detect when it needs to run.

Comment: @jpo38 That's good to hear. If you really need it to not run the first time, you could try using another generator, such as Ninja. It seems Visual Studio supports it since the [2017 15.3 preview](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/cmake-support-in-visual-studio-whats-new-in-2017-15-3-update/).

Comment: But I need to find a way to make this work with CMake and VS2015.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a "workaround", not a "solution".

I simply add a status file to tell when generate called from VS should be skipped because I know the solution is up-to-date:

Add new argument to the parser:

```
parser.add_argument('--from_vs', action='store_true', help='identify that configure is ran from VS to prevent useless regeneration, don't set this manually please')
```

Correctly maintain this file from the script itself:

```
vs_force_up_to_date_file = os.path.join( buildfolder, "vs_force_up_to_date" )
if args.from_vs:
    is_up_to_date = False

    if os.path.isfile( vs_force_up_to_date_file ):
        with open( vs_force_up_to_date_file, "r" ) as file:
            content = file.readlines()[0]
            is_up_to_date = ( content == "True" )

    if is_up_to_date:
        # It's the first time VS runs this script, we know it is up-to-date, so let's not regenerate
        # See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59861101/cmake-how-can-i-make-add-custom-command-output-up-to-date-by-default
        print( "First time calling generate from VS, project is likely up-to-date, let's not reconfigure!" )
        # Make next generate from VS be skipped
        with open( vs_force_up_to_date_file, "w" ) as file:
            file.write( str(False) )
        exit(0)
    else:
        # need to generate, let's continue!
        pass
else:
    # Generating from console, let's make VS believe it is up to date for first time it will generate
    if os.path.isfile( vs_force_up_to_date_file ):
        # Let the file as it is, "True" if VS generate never ran, else False
        pass
    else:
        # Create the file to prevent first VS generate to rerun this script while it does not need to be ran
        with open( vs_force_up_to_date_file, "w" ) as file:
            file.write( str(True) )
```

Make this new argument be set when ran from VS:

```
run_args = " ".join( [ x.replace("\\","/") for x in sys.argv] )
if not args.from_vs:
    run_args += " --from_vs"
maincmakelists.write( "add_custom_command( OUTPUT " + cmakelistspath.replace("\\","/") + " COMMAND python " + run_args + " WORKING_DIRECTORY " + working_directory.replace("\\","/") + " DEPENDS " + prgnamepath.replace("\\","/") + ")\n" )
```

This makes VS useless call to configure on first generate request be skipped and leter, needed calls will work as expected.

### Edit

Actually, this does not work as well as expected. Because VS runs the script every first time for every configuration. So after you build once in Release mode, switching to Debug will end up generating again the CMakeLists.txt while it should not because first generation wrote False in vs_force_up_to_date file. This is a too naive solution.

Instead, the solution I finally adopted is to pass the path to all input files (prgname.txt) and output files (CMakeLists.txt) to the script and have it check if all outputs are more recent than all inputs, skip the generation. Then, whatever unexpected call to the script VS may do, they will be handled correctly by the script itself.